# How does STAB work exactly, and how does it interact with the Technician ability?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-fourth-generation

A Pokemon which has the Technitian ability gets x1.5 boosted attack power for all moves used which have an attack power of 60 or less (so a move with 60 attack power will actually have 90 attack power).
STAB (Same type attack bonus) gives a 50% boost to damage, assuming the attack has the same type as the Pokemon using it (so a Grass Pokemon using Razor Leaf will do 1.5 times the damage). However, I have seen contradicting information, so currently I do not know whether STAB boosts the actual damage or the move's attack power.

What I would like to know, first, is the precise manner in which a STAB is applied to an attack.
Secondly, I would like to know what happens if an attack which would be affected by the Technician ability is also affected by STAB (though this answer might vary depending on the actual way that STABs work).

For example, my Scyther has the Technitian ability and attacks using the "Wing Attack" attack, which is a Flying-type attack with 60 attack power. Since Scyther is a Bug/Flying type pokemon he should also get a STAB for this attack, so just what is the eventual attack power/damage in this case?

(Please answer for 4th generation mechanics)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Power of an attack directly correlates to how much damage you deal, because its presence in the damage formula is entirely multiplicative. So, an attack with 120 power will do twice as much damage as one that has 60 power. The same goes with your corresponding attack stat: a Pokemon with 100 Attack will do twice as much damage as one with 50 Attack when using the same attack on the same target.

STAB has operated consistently since Gen 1 so this applies to all of the games. It increases the Power of an attack by 50% if it matches one of your types. 60 becomes 90, for instance.

Technician increases the Base Power of an attack by 50% if its Power is 60 or less. So the most you get is boosting an attack at 60 power to 90. This occurs **before** STAB is calculated, so your Power would be 90 for STAB, boosting it to 135.

Answer (score 6):

The formula for attack damage can be found from [bulbapedia.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Damage_modification)
The formula for it is:

```
Damage = ( (2 x level + 10 / 250) x (attack/defense) x base + 2) x modifier
```

The part you're interested in is the modifier, it is calculated as:

```
modifier = STAB x Type x Critical X other X random[0.85,1]
```

In your case the the technician makes the other variable 1.5 when attack > 60. And when getting a STAB bonus, the stab variable is replaced by 1.5. So in your case STAB and technician should stack according to the information found from bulbapedia.

Answer (score 3):

The STAB boost is calculated after the Technician boost. So in your specific example, the damage of Wing Attack is 60 x 1.5 x 1.5 = **135 base power**.