# How does Technician interact with variable-power moves in 7th gen?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation

I am really confused about how the Technician ability works. The ability text states "*Powers up the Pokémon's weaker moves.*" and Serebii says "*Moves with a base power of 60 or less are boosted in power by 50%.*"

I have these two scenarios that I would like to ask about:

1. What is the base power of Acrobatics if the Pokemon has Technician?

   According to Bulbapedia, Acrobatics' has 55 base power (BP) when holding an item, or 110 BP when not holding an item.

   Is it correct to say that Technician will apply to Acrobatics if the Pokemon is holding an item, but it will not apply if it isn't?
2. How about with the Same-Type Attack Bonus (STAB)?

   Suppose a Bug Type Pokemon with Technician knows Fury Cutter.
   Fury Cutter has 40 BP. But due to STAB, it becomes 60 BP. Then with Technician, I assume that it becomes 90 BP.

   Now the problem lies on its secondary effect: Fury Cutter grows more powerful in each hit. Based on what was written in Bulbapedia, for each successful consecutive hit it doubles in power (as of Generation VI).

   If I used Fury Cutter twice, then it has 80 BP, or 120 BP with STAB. Now how does Technician work? Does it no longer apply to the move?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does STAB work exactly, and how does it interact with the Technician ability?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5241/how-does-stab-work-exactly-and-how-does-it-interact-with-the-technician-ability)

Comment: Phoenix, I made an edit in an attempt to clarify what you're asking. Please revise further or rollback as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you asked for 7th gen, but as of now [there is no proof](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/updatedabilities.shtml) that [Technician](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Technician_(Ability)) has changed.

So yes, Technician only applies to the original *Acrobatics* with a base power of 55.

In the same way, Techician is applied only to the first *Fury Cutter*, because it's the only one to have a base power of 60 or less.

---

And regarding:

> The base power of Fury Cutter is 40.
>   But because it is a STAB move, it becomes 60.
>   Since the rule of Technician applies, is it safe to assume that the **base power now becomes** 90?

This is wrong. Base Power is still 40, you don't have to add STAB before applying an Ability effect. Calculating the STAB and Technician modifiers you obtain that the move has an actual power of 90.

Comment: Nothing upsets me more when talking about Pokémon than people saying "the Base Power after modifications is". Base means base, dammit!

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yap, there's always a bit of misconception about that.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm sorry if I upset you with my question. But please, tell me this: Was there a time where you asked a question that the answer was so obvious, there was no need to ask it about it? Hm? Well, not everyone can be as keen as you are. The reason I asked is because I want to know if I am correct or not. Is it not this website made to answer questions for NEWBIE PLAYERS or THOSE THAT WANT ANSWERS? I even saw questions in regards to using the Pokemon Centre, but I kept quiet knowing that, in turn, they would also felt the need to help players that cannot solve the simplest things.